# Read local file react native

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to read a text file from my local filesystem using
[react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

However, it keeps telling me the file does not exist (It does, I double checked it and tried to copy the into the run window).

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import FileSystem from 'react-native-filesystem';

import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NetInfo
} from 'react-native';


export default class FactsApiFetcher extends Component
{ 
  constructor(props)
  {    
    super(props);   
    this.state =
    {
      fact: 'Loading...'
    } 
  }   

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this._getRandomFact();
  }

  _getRandomFact()
  {
    const fileContents = RNFS.read("D:\\AllRand\\facts-api-handler\\test.txt") //FileSystem.readFile("D:\\AllRand\\allfacts\\test.txt");    

   this.setState({
      fact: fileContents
    }) 
  }

  render()
  {    
    return <Text> { this.state.fact } </Text>;
  }  
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('FactsApiFetcher', () => FactsApiFetcher);
```

Comment: Have you set up the configuration? https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#usage-android, and there is an example usage too there.

Comment: From the documentation https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilepath-string-length--0-position--0-encodingoroptions-any-promisestring you need to return promise when use method `read()`

Answer (score 4):

You should bundle your files into app or put them inside Simulator or Device manually. When you run application it could explore only it's own filesystem, and it can't explre your Windows FS. Use this constants https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants to get access to files.